# Add values from UserForm starting in specific column and cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form which adds input information from VBA UserForm into dedicated cells, e.g. First Name, Last Name, I'm using `iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row` to find an empty row, and to add information in a specific column of the row. By default, the information is printed on B1, is it possible to change it to G7 for example?

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.txt_firstname
    ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.txt_lastname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your row count to this:

```
iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

If iRow<7 then
iRow =7
End if 

ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.txt_firstname
```

This will change your cell count to at least row 7, if the first cell is later than that, it will add it to next empty row after that.

Comment: Thank you, Pete! :)